# AWS S3 Glacier - Mount S3 Glacier as partition on *nix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, amazon-glacier

There already exists `s3fs` to mount an S3 bucket as partition on *nix. But there is similar alternative to mount S3 Glacier as a partition on a system?

Comment: Even if there was one, how would it work? Files/objects in Glacier are not readily available. You would have to wait hours to get access to any of them, or pay for expedited retrials and wait minutes for every single file you want to access.

Comment: Amazon S3 is an object storage system, not a filesystem. It is not recommended to use tools to mount S3 as a disk volume, especially for production workloads. What are you _actually_ wanting to achieve as your higher-level goal?